# Pronunciation guide by a Gerer Rebbe?

Tags: books-generally, product-recommendation, pronunciation, chasidut-hasidism

I heard from a friend years ago that one of the [Rebbe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebbe#Chasidic_Rebbeim)s from [Gur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B3ra_Kalwaria) (the [*S'fas Emes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehudah_Aryeh_Leib_Alter)) wrote a book describing the proper pronunciation of Hebrew letters and words. I am not able to find any trace of such a book online and I wouldn't know how to search for it in real life. Does it exist?

This is of particular interest because it seems *chasidei Ger* have a distinct system of pronunciation.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/

Comment: @DoubleAA then edit the question to "Is there a book by the Gerrer Rebbe..."

Comment: @ShmuelBrill That sounds even more Too Localized!

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the question is specific enough to allow someone who knows about the book to identify what is being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is called *Sfat Emet Siftei Kohen* (שפת אמת שפתי כהן), and it was authored by R' Bentzion HaKohen. You can find copies for purchase [here](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Shop/item/67) and [here](http://www.wslibrary.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=1768&language=en), although I regret that it's nearly impossible to find anything *about* it. It has nothing to do with the Gerrer Rebbe, and the pronunciation for which it serves as a guide has nothing to do with Gerrer pronunciation. On the contrary, he seems to advocate an approximation of an eastern pronunciation (Teimani, Baghdadi, etc), and devotes a great deal of attention to carefully explicating every letter and every vowel. It's ironic, therefore, that some people might refer to it as Sefer Sefas Emes, since this is the very pronunciation that its author is militating against!

My only source for all of this is the fact that I've flicked through it, briefly. I do not own it, nor have I succeeded in finding anything useful about it online.

Comment: as i have commented below the sefer is in otzar hachochmah

Answer (score 1):

there is a sefer sfas emes on the topic but not written by the sfas emes rather  contemporary author 5747.

maybe you misunderstood 'sfas emes'

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any more information on it?

Comment: see otzar hachochma