# origin of chassidish havarah(pronunciation)

Tags: history, hebrew, pronunciation, chasidut-hasidism

When did people start using the chassidish havarah? If making that change was deliberate, who instituted it?

I remember seeing some where that it was started to oppose the maskilim who where medakdek on dikduk, but I have a hard time believing this. Hence, my question.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/kubutz-and-shuruk-in-polish-hungarian-pronunciation).

Comment: stronglyer related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18529/759

Comment: Which pronunciation do you mean? You may wish to clarify: there are several different pronunciations used in different Chassidic groups.

Comment: perhaps relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14956/759

Comment: A recent book on this subject has come out by someone Dembitser of Edgeware. Although he agrees its 'wrong' he spells out the exact way to say the chasidish havarah. In the haskomo of Rav H Heilpern of Brooklyn he admonishes him for it. Whats the point of teaching how to read chasidish if its admittedly wrong.

Comment: @sam http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_37013_161.pdf